# Non-distinct Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
4&\alpha&-1\\
2&5&\beta\\
1&1&\gamma
\end{pmatrix}$$

Be a *diagonalisable* matrix, with eigenvalues 3,3$,\delta$ (and $\delta \neq3$). Find the values of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and $\delta$.

**Approach**: Using $|A-3I|=0$, we get $(2\gamma -6-\beta)(1-\alpha)=0$.

Next, we can use that $tr(A)=9+\gamma=6+\delta$, i.e $\delta =\gamma +3$.
we can further use $|A-\delta I|=0$, and also, $9\delta =|A|$.

However, the last two equations make the computations incredibly messy, and thus it made me think that there is probably a nice argument that will simplify some of these computations....

Now,We also need to include the constraint of $A$ being diagonalisable.(i.e $A$ must have 3 linearly independent eigenvectors).However, it has only two *distinct* eigenvalues.Thus, there must be *2* linearly independent solutions to either $(A-\delta I)x=0$, or to $(A-3I)x=0$ i.e, the rank of $A-\delta I$ , or $(A-3I)$ must be $1$.

I tried it with $(A-3I)$, and got the (correct) answer immediately: ($\alpha=1$,$\beta=-2,\gamma=2,$ and $\delta =3+\gamma=5$.

However, who do I show that trying to make the rank of the other one, i.e $A-\delta I$ =$1$, does **not** get the correct answer?

Comment: $A-3I$ is similar to $D-3I$ whose rank is $1$. D is the diagonal matrix $(3,3,\delta)$

Comment: If $A - \delta I$ has rank $1$, then $A$ has the eigenvalue $\delta$ with multiplicity (at least) $2$, which is not what we want